# In google visualization array to data table (to table chart) how do I make a cell a multi-line string?

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have data I want to enter into a table chart and some of the data is multiline. I can use a replace function to replace the new lines with something else, but testing has given me nothing that works.

Here's my test code so far

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Name'],
['Tong \n Ning mu'],
['Huang Ang fa'],
['Teng nu']
]);

var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
chartType: 'Table',
dataTable: data,
options: {'title': 'Countries'},
containerId: 'visualization'
});
wrapper.draw();
```

The \n does not get replaced with a new line. Neither does \r\n. They both just disappear.

Edit: I found one solution below but is there any way to do it without using html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the HTML line creak: `<br />`, and set the Table's `allowHtml` option to `true`:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Name'],
    ['Tong<br />Ning mu'],
    ['Huang Ang fa'],
    ['Teng nu']
]);

var wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
        'title': 'Countries',
        allowHtml: true
    },
    containerId: 'visualization'
});
wrapper.draw();
```

Comment: Well that works, so does plain old <br>. Slightly off topic but are there any disadvantages to <br> in general?

Comment: Disadvantages to `<br>` vs `<br />`, or are you talking about something else?  AFAIK, the reason to use `<br />` is because strict HTML requires all tags to be closed, including tags that would otherwise be interpreted as self-closing tags (like `<br>`, `<hr>`, `<img>`).

Comment: are there any solutions that don't use html? There was some html style tags in the column, and what if I wanted to display those as tags?

Comment: No, there is no way to get a line break in HTML without using HTML.  If you need to display a string-literal HTML tag, then you need to input it HTML-encoded, eg `'<br />'` would be `'&lt;br /&gt;'`